# Correct way to run a docker script in Jenkins pipeline that runs and quits

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

I have a docker container that does some FTP activity that takes 3-7 minutes then ends. My Jenkins pipeline snippet looks like this:

```
    stage('Run image'){
      sh '''
      docker run -i -v \
      --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)/host-dirs,target=/host-dirs" \
      chq-ic2e-sprint-images-docker-local.artifactory.swg-devops.com/ssc-cost-file-processor:approved
      sh
      '''
    }
```

However, docker says

```
docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.
```

If this were a terminal, I'd use the -it function but that's not applicable here. I want the script to do its thing then end.

For testing purposes, I run it from a terminal like this and it works fine:

```
#!/bin/bash
docker run -it \
 --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)/host-dirs,target=/host-dirs" \
 chq-ic2e-sprint-images-docker-local.artifactory.swg-devops.com/ssc-cost-file-processor:approved sh
```

Comment: You have both `-v` and `--mount` options, which is confusing things; remove the `-v`.  `docker.inside('image:tag') { sh '...' }` might be easier to run, and will automatically bind-mount the Jenkins workdir into the container.

Comment: @DavidMaze I think it was late and I must have overlooked the -v. So many commands use that as a verbose option that I didn't even think of it as short for volume. Would like to mark your answer correct if I could find that link.